# How do I securely remap the current split's width and height keys?

Tags: key-bindings

Iam trying to put `nnoremap <C-Right> <C-w>3>`  in the ~/.vimrc

But it's not working. Also, VIM has a PRETTY ANNOYING  line erasing binding to ctrl+Right in the Normal Mode.
I would like to deactivate  this erasing and do split resize with Ctrl + Arrows.

How is the most secure way to config this  ?

thank you

Comment: The mapping works for me. It should work for you too. Try to check if some other keybinding is clashing with it or maybe there is some error in the `vimrc`

Comment: `Also, VIM has a PRETTY ANNOYING line erasing binding to ctrl+Right` This is not the default setting. Check your terminal setup.

Comment: Ctrl keys are difficult to bind; not all terminals allow all keys to be bound (eg on mac its impossible because C-right is an OS level key)

Comment: @klaus  "Try to check if some other keybinding is clashing" and @Matt "Check your terminal setup",  you mean in the ```vim .vimrc```  file ?

Comment: Execute `:verb nmap <C-Right>` to find out if and where a mapping for Ctrl+Right is defined.

Comment: Is there an analogous way to do this search for the mapping in the Bash Terminal commands? Seems to be that its line deleting mapping is interfering in VIM modes.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Mac has non-overridable, global control-key shortcuts? a) inane b) good to know c) wouldn't Apple/Command key make more sense for such a thing?

Comment: @BLayer agree/disagree—im not sure if one can disable it or not, but C-left/right switches desktops (i can have many desktops on a single computer, a bit like Ubuntu’s old workspaces thing). It’s useful to me.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Useful to you and lots of other people, I'm sure. My comment is only applicable if such shortcuts are forced on ordinary apps. (If, e.g., one can only change via some system config window). That would be a bummer, IMO. That's all I meant.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Does Bash Terminal has the overridability? i cant find resource on this though.